# Equivalent of "script" command in Windows Shellscript?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

There is [**script**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm) command on GNU/Linux machine which allows to capture all command line activity into a file . This is really helpful tool especially when we learn something new and we want to save the commands and their output for future reference.

I am currently learning the Git on [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) terminal and I wanted to capture all the commands and their output in a file for future reference.

Is there any way/command  do achieve it on Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `Start-Transcript` and  `Stop-Transcript` cmdlet.

You can also use [Start-Transcript for ISE Editor module](http://www.powertheshell.com/transcript/) because **these CmdLet don't work natively in ISE**.

Comment: Thanks for the the site PowerTheShell.com, there are plenty of good things inside.

Answer (score 5):

It exists standard CmdLets : `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript`.

You'll find more informations about these CmdLet in the [associeted TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx).

Comment: I answered first, but @why answer is more complete.

Comment: no your answer is more complete because the documentation ( merci beaucoup mais c'est ton mérite moi je n'ai fait que répété ce que t'as dit en premier)